# Converting date column with month abbreviations to readable date format

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, seaborn

I have a Pandas DataFrame and I am trying to convert the month abbreviations in the Date column to a format I can use in Seaborn plots later. Here is an example of a section of the data.

```
data = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'Date': ['Jan 5, 2023', 'Feb 20, 2023', 'Mar 30, 2023']}
```

I'm newer to Python and I've been trying to piece together code from other posts and it feels like nothing is coming together correctly. Ideally I would like it to be done in place and the result be something I can use for time series charts later in my analysis, like `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I was able to strip the months out but I don't know how to do that in place without removing the day and year while also reordering them.

```
df['month']= df['Date'].astype(str).str[:3]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: if you want YYYY-MM-DD datetime : `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` if you want YYYY-MM-DD str : `pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'Date': ['Jan 5, 2023', 'Feb 20, 2023', 'Mar 30, 2023', 'Apr 15, 2023']}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'Date' column to datetime format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Convert month abbreviations to full month names
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   ID        Date
0   1  2023-01-05
1   2  2023-02-20
2   3  2023-03-30
3   4  2023-04-15
```

Comment: Wow I made this a lot more complicated than it had to be. This works great thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To convert the Date column from the format with the month abbreviation use pd.to_datetime().

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'Date': ['Jan 5, 2023', 'Feb 20, 2023', 'Mar 30, 2023']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert the 'Date' column to datetime format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# you can also run this if the previous line doesn't work properly alone
# df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```